# My form key is not validating in flutter, even after i used it as key in form and entering suitable values

Tags: android, ios, forms, flutter, dart

Ok I saw posts regarding this error, but I was not able to figure out, why my `_formKey` is not validating. I used it in `key` parameter in `Form`, still it is not validating.

How I was able to figure that out? I just used an if statement, in the function, which is at the last of given code (i.e. at line 142). I used -

```
if(_formKey.currentState!.validate())
    print("Yes");
```

And I got nothing as output. So please can someone tell me where am i missing a point. I am writing line numbers down below, that can be helpful and save some time-

Line no. - 24, 51, 74, 82, 94, 100, 142.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_instagram_clone_final/Screens/signup/cubit/signup_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_instagram_clone_final/repositories/auth/auth_repository.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  static const String routeName = '/signup';

  static Route route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: const RouteSettings(
        name: routeName,
      ),
      builder: (context) => BlocProvider<SignupCubit>(
        create: (_) => SignupCubit(authRepository: context.read<AuthRepository>()),
        child: SignupScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: BlocConsumer<SignupCubit, SignupState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if(state.status==SignupStatus.error)
                showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Error'),
                  content: Text(state.failure.message),),
                );
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                body: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                        child: Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Instagram',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.075,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 12.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter the username",
                                ),
                                onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignupCubit>().usernameChanged(value),
                                validator: (value) => value!.trim().isNotEmpty ? "" : 'Please enter a valid email',
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter the email",
                                ),
                                onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignupCubit>().emailChanged(value),
                                validator: (value) => EmailValidator.validate(value??"") ? "" : 'Please enter a valid email',
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 12.0,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                obscureText: true,
                                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter the password",
                                ),
                                onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignupCubit>().passwordChanged(value),
                                validator: (value) => value!.length<6 ? "Must be at least 6 characters" : '',
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20.0,
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () => _submitForm(context, state.status==SignupStatus.submitting),
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  elevation: 1.0,
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 12.0,
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.grey[200],
                                  elevation: 1.0,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Already have an account? Log In',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submitForm(BuildContext context, bool isSubmitting) {
    print('${_formKey.currentState} $isSubmitting');
    if(_formKey.currentState!.validate() && !isSubmitting)
      context.read<SignupCubit>().signupWithCredentials();
  }
}
```

P.S. : I'm entering email, password and username as - s@s.com, 123456, Sf respectively as a sample. So I think my entered values are correct, there is some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

In vaidator callback you have to return null when your validations works, that's because the validate isn't working

```
TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Enter the password",
      ),
      onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignupCubit>().passwordChanged(value),
      // Return null in validator when the validation is ok
      validator: (value) =>
          value!.length < 6 ? "Must be at least 6 characters" : null,
    )
```

If null is returned, then validator will return true and the print should be called

Comment: You mean, i should return null in if statement in submitform function?

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother.